# making dynamic ajax web application searchable

Tags: java, ajax, gwt

I have developed ajax web application that is constantly generating new Dynamic pages with ID ( like http://www.enggheads.com/#! question/1419242644475) 
when some one add question on website.
I have made my ajax web application crawlable, I have implemented this as this Link recommended 
LINK : https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ 
and tested that 'fetch as google' returns the html snaphots. and tested on facebook developer tools it also fetch data accurately. I've submitted a site map with all the current urls. but when we search, only some of the links of sitemap show in google search result. and google refuses to index any of the ajax links, although there are no crawl errors.
1--My Question: So what else I have to do to show all link of my apllication in google search result.
2--My Question: And One more question I have to ask is, as I explain above that this application is generating new dynamic pages so we have to regenerate the sitemap eachtime(or at set interval) when some one add a question on my web. Or is there any other significant way to handle this situation.
And dont't know  how "Facebook.com" , "Stackoverflow.com" , "in.linkedin.com" manage their sitemap if they use...???